# How to make a function which change lowercase to uppercase and vice verse?

Tags: r

Can you please help, how to write a function which change little letters to big and vice verse in R?

Comment: An alternative is `caseflip` from `ds4psy` package.  `# install.packages("ds4psy")
library(ds4psy)

string <- c("MaN", "woMEn")
caseflip(string)
[1] "mAn"   "WOmeN"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example string

```
mystring = "This Is aN ExAmPlE sTRING"
```

See `?chartr` for details but its used like this `chartr(old,new,x)`. Here we are flipping the lower case and uppercase letters so the old is the reverse of the new and what we want to change (x) is the string.
Function:

```
myfunct <- function(string){
  chartr("a-zA-Z", "A-Za-z",string)
}
```

call function:

```
myfunct(mystring)
```

Output:

```
[1] "tHIS iS An eXaMpLe String"
```